# Search dynamically allocated vector for specific data? C++

Tags: c++, search, vector, dynamic-allocation

I have to create a dynamically allocated vector of objects from the Resistor class, which only has two private variables: resistance and tolerance. After that, a function must be created in order to search the vector for those objects that have resistance and tolerance equal to the values passed in the function's argument.

After searching for a while, I have no idea how to implement this. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you expect the output of this function to be? Another container with the matching elements? A container with the indices of those elements in the first container? A container with iterators or pointers to those elements?

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement the comparison operator `operator==(const Resistor&)` of your Resistor class.
2. Use `std::find` to search the vector for the data by supplying a new Resistor instance created from the function arguments.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/